# drag and drop images from one layout to another

Tags: android, android-studio

i have implemented drag and drop images from horizontal scroll view to another layout in which surface view of camera is available and when i drop the image the layout which contains images removes but i don't want so. please help me i have searched a-lot but not got. My XML and java codes are here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main" tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <SurfaceView
        android:id="@+id/surfaceView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:scrollbars="none"
    android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/inhorizontalscrollview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/civ"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:src="@drawable/a"/>

    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements SurfaceHolder.Callback, View.OnTouchListener, View.OnDragListener {

private static final String LOGCAT = "CamTestActivity";

SurfaceView cameraView;
SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
Camera camera;
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params;

int[] img={R.drawable.a, R.drawable.b, R.drawable.c, R.drawable.d, R.drawable.e, R.drawable.f};


RelativeLayout fm;
LinearLayout inHorizontalScrollView;
ImageView civ;

int width,height;


@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB_MR2)
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.content_main);
    /*Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);*/

    inHorizontalScrollView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.inhorizontalscrollview);        

    /*FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });*/


    fm = ((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout));

    civ = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.civ);

    inHorizontalScrollView.setOnDragListener(this);
    civ.setOnTouchListener(this);
    fm.setOnDragListener(this);
    //findViewById(R.id.mainLayout).setOnDragListener(this);
    cameraView = (SurfaceView) this.findViewById(R.id.surfaceView);
    surfaceHolder = cameraView.getHolder();
    surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);

    Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    width = size.x;
    height = size.y;
    Log.d(LOGCAT, "width = "+width+"   height = "+height);

    /*for(int i=0;i<img.length;i++){
        //Log.v("on recent frnds", "on post execute");
        //if(recfrnd.get(i).length()>1){
            //Log.v("on recent frnds", "in if   "+recfrnd.get(i));
            civ = new ImageView(MainActivity.this);
            civ.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(120, 120));
            civ.setPadding(0, 0, 25, 0);
            civ.setImageResource(img[i]);
        inHorizontalScrollView.addView(civ);
        civ.setOnLongClickListener(this);


    }*/

}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



@Override
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera = Camera.open();
    try {
        camera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
        Camera.Parameters parameters = camera.getParameters();
        if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE) {
            parameters.set("orientation", "portrait");
            camera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
        }
        camera.setParameters(parameters);
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        camera.release();
    }
}

@Override
public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width, int height) {
    camera.startPreview();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    camera.stopPreview();
    camera.release();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        View.DragShadowBuilder shadowBuilder = new View.DragShadowBuilder(view);
        view.startDrag(null, shadowBuilder, view, 0);
        //view.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        return true;
    }
    else {
        return false;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onDrag(View layoutview, DragEvent dragevent) {
    int x_cord=0,y_cord=0;
    int action = dragevent.getAction();
    switch (action) {
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_STARTED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event started");
            return true;
            //break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENTERED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event entered into "+layoutview.toString());
            if(layoutview.getId()==R.id.layout) {
               // params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) layoutview.getLayoutParams();
                params=new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(civ.getWidth(),civ.getHeight());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
           // break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_EXITED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag event exited from "+layoutview.toString());
            return false;
            //break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped");
            View view = (View) dragevent.getLocalState();
            ViewGroup owner = (ViewGroup) view.getParent();
            ViewGroup container = (ViewGroup) layoutview;
            owner.removeView(view);
            if(layoutview.getId()==R.id.layout) {
               // RelativeLayout container = (RelativeLayout)layoutview;
                x_cord = (int) dragevent.getX();
                y_cord = (int) dragevent.getY();
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped  x="+x_cord+"    y="+y_cord+"   w="+civ.getWidth()+"    h="+civ.getHeight());
                if(x_cord+civ.getWidth()>width){
                    int min = x_cord+civ.getWidth()-width;
                    x_cord = x_cord-min;
                }
                if(y_cord+civ.getHeight()>height){
                    int min = y_cord+civ.getHeight()-height;
                    y_cord = y_cord - min;
                }
                params.leftMargin = x_cord;
                params.topMargin = y_cord;
                Log.d(LOGCAT, "Dropped  x=" + x_cord + "    y=" + y_cord + "   w=" + civ.getWidth() + "    h=" + civ.getHeight());
                //v.setLayoutParams(params);
                //view.setX(x_cord);
                //view.setY(y_cord);
                container.addView(view, params);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }else{
               // LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) layoutview;
                container.addView(view);
                view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            }
            return true;
            //break;
        case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED:
            Log.d(LOGCAT, "Drag ended");
            return false;
            //break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    return false;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One view is visible in only that layout area show you can not see that image in another layout for this problem you have to create a fake layout with width and height with match parent and add your view at run time on that fake layout at the view position and drag where you want after drag invisible the fake layout.